# redraw canvas with wave form js

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, soundcloud, waveform

i have to make a sound player like soundcloud player.
so i used a ubuntu based software to build json data for use in `waveformjs.org` jquery library
this part is working good and have a canvas of my image like this:

```
waveform = new Waveform({
  container: document.getElementById("test"),
  data: newJ,
  innerColor:"#f60",
});
```

[image: canvas]

but the problem is when i have to show music playback process status.
like soudcloud every second a part of the canvas color must change 
but the internal function of `wavweforjs` for this part , (`optionsForSyncedStream`) dont working for me ...

do you know how can i implement this part?!
also how about repaint the canvas manually ??? is it possible to change color of a part of the drown canvas by x and y position ?!?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its possible to use `innerColor` to change a part of waveformjs plugin.

for this must :

```
innerColor: function(x, y){
if (typeof(i)=='undefined'){i=0;}
i++;
  if(i>audioElement.currentTime){
      return 'gray';
  }else{
      return '#f60';
  }
}
```

Then should to check the positions every X seconds and update the waveform like this :

```
setInterval(function(){
    waveform.update({data:data}); 
    i=0;
}, 100);
```

This is not a clean way but working good in my end..

Answer (score 1):

To be a bit more verbose: you can pass a custom function to innerColor when you first create a new Waveform.

Taking a look at the [source](https://github.com/soundcloud/waveformjs/blob/master/views/waveform.coffee#L52) of the Waveform.js library, you can see that they check to see if you have passed in a function for innerColor and if so, they pass a few items to your function to generate the color:

```
// The source is in Coffeescript
i = 0
for d in @data
  t = @width / @data.length
  // This line is the one I'm referring to...
  @context.fillStyle = @innerColor(i/@width, d) if typeof(@innerColor) == "function"
  @context.clearRect t*i, middle - middle * d, t, (middle * d * 2)
  @context.fillRect t*i, middle - middle * d, t, middle * d * 2
  i++
```

So they loop through each 'line' in the waveform and `i/@width` (which is passed to your innerColor function) is essentially the location of the line (expressed as a percentage from the start) of the waveform that they are currently trying to draw the color for. If you take that percentage and figure out if the audio track's `currentTime` is above/below that number, you can give the 'line' a specific color as such:

```
waveform = new Waveform({
   container: document.getElementById('waveform'),
   innerColor: function(percentageOfWaveform, d) {
     // We don't need d
     var songPercentage = yourAudioElement.currentTime / yourAudioElement.duration;
     if (percentageOfWaveform > songPercentage) {
       return 'gray';
     } else {
       return '#f60';
     }
   }
});
```

Then you'll have to write some logic to redraw the waveform every so often so that it updates.

```
waveform.redraw()
```

*It should be noted that I am using HTML5 audio as opposed to the standard SC.stream method of the SDK, so `yourAudioElement` is an HTML5 audio element.